# Method to redirect website subfolder to new website in IIS

Tags: url-rewriting, iis

We currently have a website, let's call it `https://supersystem.example.com`
We also offer customized versions of the website to clients, in the past we would throw those custom files into a sub3folder and the client would access it via `https://supersystem.example.com/client1/`

The software has been upgraded and now has different architecture so that will no longer work. Now each custom site needs to be its own website in IIS.

What I'd like to avoid doing is `https://client1.supersystem.example.com` because I would like to keep using our *.example.com wildcard SSL cert.

So one option is `https://client1-supersystem.example.com`
But I'm curious if with URL Rewrite if I could make `https://supersystem.example.com/client1/` go to `https://supersystem.example.com:8081` for example and then have each of the custom websites just on different ports, 8081, 8082, etc.

1. Is that feasible?
2. If so, what would one put into the bindings for `https://supersystem.example.com:8081`, particularly the SSL binding since `supersystem.example.com` is already in the bindings for the main site on port 80/443.
3. Any other better ways to do this?

Comment: You need ARR and enable its proxy mode. Then IIS behaves like a reverse proxy and your wish can be easily fulfilled, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing